# How to Filter rows in a DataView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, html

I have a `DataGrid` that uses a `DataView` as the source. My DataView has 81 records in it. I want to filter only that rows that have an `Item_Number` that is greater than or equal to the Item the user enters. This is what I have, but its not filtering my rows.

```
PrintView.RowFilter = "Item_Number >= 'val'";
PrintView.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;

dgPrintTicket.DataSource = PrintView;
BindDataGrid();
```

`PrintView` is my DataView. When I debug and check rows after I filter the rows, it shows nothing has changed. The `PrintView` stays the same.

Comment: val between single quote is a literal string not the value of the variable val (if any exists)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is quoting the variable (`'val'`), rather you should make it like below assuming `val` is a local variable declared in your code.

```
PrintView.RowFilter = "Item_Number >=" + val;
```

Per your edit, `val` is a `string/VARCHAR` type column and so needs to be quoted like

```
PrintView.RowFilter = "Item_Number >= '" + val + "'";
```

Then not sure why you pare performing `>=` comparison in a `VARCHAR` column.

Comment: When I do that I get an error saying "Cannot find Column [F77730]". That is the Item number that is in my string 'val'.

Comment: @hmakled, what's the value in `val` variable?

Comment: The value is "F77730". Thats the Item number in the table.

Comment: @hmakled, then it should work fine. Try the edited version in answer `PrintView.RowFilter = "Item_Number >= '" + val + "'";`

Comment: I Tried that as well. Doesn't filter anything. Strange.

Comment: @hmakled, try the same directly in DB and see if it works like `select * from yourtable where Item_Number >= 'F77730'`. Can't help any further than this.